# Presto combining two columns and output as one

Tags: presto

i'm trying to combine two columns together in presto.

this is part of a query, and it has to be formatted in a certain way.

```
SELECT 'Display' AS channel, 
        DBM.dated, 
        DBM.market, 
        DBM.impressions, 
        DBM.clicks, 
        sum(DBM.amount_spent_EUR)+sum(DBm.platform_fee) as DBM.amount_spent_EUR
FROM 
(

SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_PARSE(date,'%Y/%m/%d'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS dated, 
trim(SPLIT_PART(insertion_order,'|',3)) AS market, 
sum(cast(impressions as double)) as impressions, 
sum(cast(clicks as double)) as clicks, 
sum(CAST(media_cost_advertiser_currency AS DOUBLE)*1.15) AS amount_spent_EUR,
sum(CAST(media_fee_1_adv_currency AS DOUBLE)*1.15) as platform_fee

FROM ralph_lauren_google_sheet_dbm_data_2  

WHERE dated <= {{days_ago 1}}

GROUP BY 1,2
)DBM
```

the error is as following:

> Query 20190814_125505_19433_rcrut failed: line 1:144: extraneous input
>   '.' expecting {, ',', 'EXCEPT', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING',
>   'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WHERE'}

the error is the dbm.amount_spent_eur. this column has to come out like this.
How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double quotes in such cases.

```
as "DBM.amount_spent_EUR"
```